# MySQL Server Crashing (InnoDB: Write to file ./ib_logfile0failed at offset...)

Tags: mysql, crash, innodb

I'm having a problem in a production server. My server is rebooting in aleatory times. I checked my disk with df -h and it's working with only 56% of space used. But sometimes the server crash and try to restart.

The following error occurs:

```
2019-02-12T02:26:15.412830Z 156530 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
2019-02-12T02:26:17.432993Z 156530 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ib_logfile0failed at offset 1791099392, 2048 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
2019-02-12T02:26:17.708155Z 156530 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No     space left on device'
2019-02-12T02:26:18.417133Z 156530 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system     error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2019-02-12 00:26:19 0x7fc4b0b29700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread     140482754811648 in file fil0fil.cc line 5799
InnoDB: Failing assertion: req_type.is_dblwr_recover() || err == DB_SUCCESS
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even 
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
02:26:20 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary     or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=2621440000
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=121
max_threads=1200
thread_count=65
connection_count=64
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 
52035231 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7fc4500c36f0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong... 
stack_bottom = 7fc4b0b28e80 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0xf16e3c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x451)[0x7fa791]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf890)[0x7fcea4809890]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7fcea300a187]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x118)[0x7fcea300b538]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7cb390]  /usr/sbin/mysqld(Z6fil_ioRK9IORequestbRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmmPvS8+0x772)[0x125e762]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15log_write_up_tomb+0x734)[0x1063b04]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24log_buffer_flush_to_diskb+0x108)[0x1064648]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xffe3ff]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x8406ef] /usr/sbin/mysqld(Z24plugin_foreach_with_maskP3THDPPFcS0_P13st_plugin_intPvEijS3+0x1fe)[0xd0ebfe] /usr/sbin/mysqld(Z24plugin_foreach_with_maskP3THDPFcS0_P13st_plugin_intPvEijS3+0x1d)[0xd0ed7d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13ha_flush_logsP10handlertonb+0x5a)[0x846b7a] /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13MYSQL_BIN_LOG25process_flush_stage_queueEPyPbPP3THD+0x3b)[0xeb327b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13MYSQL_BIN_LOG14ordered_commitEP3THDbb+0x10f)[0xeb344f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13MYSQL_BIN_LOG6commitEP3THDb+0x994)[0xeb66d4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15ha_commit_transP3THDbb+0x131)[0x846171]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12trans_commitP3THD+0x39)[0xd91ec9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x625)[0xce9965]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x3bd)[0xcefc3d] /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0xaba)[0xcf07ca]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x177)[0xcf21f7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x270)[0xdae930]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x1b4)[0xf91674]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x80a4)[0x7fcea48020a4]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fcea30ba7fd]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fc45004f770): commit
Connection ID (thread ID): 156530
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2019-02-12T02:26:34.937708Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 5000  (requested 6000)
```

How to repeat:
This occurs in indefinite periods. This morning the server rebooted at 2AM. At this time there is no access to the databases.

Comment: The error remains mysterious to the rest of us :)

Comment: This `1791099392` seems fairly close to 2Gig. Did you `Check that 
your OS and file system support files of this size`

Comment: Did you check `--innodb-log-file-size`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for replying so quickly.

The server has the following settings 
openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) with MySQL  5.7.21 Community Server (GPL), the file system is btrfs 

And in my.cnf the  innodb_log_file_size = 4G

Comment: I don't know how writing to the ib_logfile could ever get an error 28. The ib_logfiles are pre-allocated when you install MySQL Server, and they don't grow. So even if you do have a full disk, InnoDB will already have the space it needs, and it'll just overwrite the beginning of the logfile after it reaches the end. I'm guessing you might have a failing disk. Or else it's something strange about btrfs — I always use xfs for MySQL.

Comment: How much RAM?  How much disk space on your machine or VM?  Perhaps that was a particular query running each time it crashed?  What is the setting of `tmpdir`?  Show us your my.cnf; it sounds like you changed some values.

Comment: @BillKarwin, thank you for help, you was right, there was a problem with my file system, i change the vm to another server with CentOS with xfs partition and its stopped to crashing. Simple tasks like copy of file during troubleshoting show problems

Comment: Thanks @RickJames, i was tried checking the temdir and temptable, and was everthing ok, but i need to optmize my server configuration. I work with two instances on same server and think that the my.conf and the my2.conf both need a better attencion on memory, but i will go to create a new post about this. For now is everthing ok with my new server